# How to add a child control to a TActionToolBar?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a `TActionManager` setup with various actions which are then displayed in both a `TActionMainMenuBar` and a `TActionToolBar`.

What I require is to be able to display a `TComboBox` as a child to the `TActionToolBar`. I tried creating a new `TActionClientItem` and changing the CommandStyle to `csComboBox` and assigning my `TComboBox` to the ContainedControl property but at runtime there is no change, ie the combo box is not shown as a child control in the `TActionToolBar`.

I have tried toggling and changing several properties within the `TActionClientItem` with no luck, I then turned to the help docs and found the following:

> Use CommandStyle to change the behavior and the appearance of an action client item located on a ribbon group. CommandStyle has no effect if the action client item is not located on a ribbon group.

So I guess CommandStyle  was misleading me and hence changing those properties had no effect because I am not using a ribbon control.

Due to the design of my Application I don't want to switch to other controls such as `TToolBar` or `TCoolBar` for example. Is it possible to allow child controls such as a `TComboBox` to be used on a `TActionToolBar`?

Comment: AFAICT, this is not possible. If you drop the combobox on the ActionToolBar, it is parented by the underlying form. If you try to use the Structure View to drag and drop it on the ActionToolBar, the cursor changes to the *you can't do that* circle/slash. This indicates to me that the ActionToolBar is not designed to support combobox controls. Have you considered putting the ActionToolBar onto a different container (such as a TCoolBar or TPanel), and then putting the combobox there?

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your input, I had considered dropping the ActionToolBar onto a TCoolBar and then adding the combo box but I don't like this design choice. I think I will live without the combo box for now and maybe revisit my options later on, I just like the way the Action Bars are managed and really don't understand why it's not possible to do something like this.